# css overflow related , i have to overflow a specific item in the container

Tags: css, user-interface, overflow

the container mobile is a div and each paragraph is a div
i want to overflow hidden
but only for last two paragraphs ( i.e Div )
not the first two paragraphs
and if i do overflow hidden in mobile container so it will hide all
anyone knows the solution please ?
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMmS8.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a container class like `class = container` in your css file. If I try to understand you, you want to select the last two elements? You can select them by using this pseudo elements `:nth-last-child()`.

Try using this code to select the last two div elements:

```
.container>div:nth-last-child(1) {

}
```

and

```
.container>div:nth-last-child(2) {

}
```

Comment: heyy thnx to answer but i m unable to di it yet
can u dm me on discord pls :- Kartik Sharma#6198

Comment: I have sent you a friend request.